# ExtJs grid - Disable row selection on click of cell editor

Tags: extjs, extjs5

Is there a way(config) in ExtJs to disable row selection(I am using checkbox SelectionModel) when user clicks on the editable cell. 
I want to make this deselection on conditional basis.

Comment: Did you try `disableSelection : true` check fiddle https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/1hbo

Comment: @UDID disableSelection will wont allow selection even on click of check box. I want to keep the selection on click of checkbox

Answer (score 2):

### Use checkOnly: true in selectionModel then it will check only when you click on checkbox same appicable for deselection also

```
selModel: {
                selType: 'checkboxmodel',
                checkOnly: true,
                allowDeselect: false,
       }
```

reference: https://fiddle.sencha.com/#fiddle/8jp

Comment: I have already used checkOnly: true config. But on click of editable cell the row is again getting selected. I want to avoid this selection of row on click of editable cell.